# Append JavaScript variable to option element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a table with combo box in my jsp :

```
<form:form modelAttribute="mainCommodity" id="mainCommodityForm">
  <table id="customPostTable" >
    <td>
        <form:select path="postId">
            <form:option value="0" id="PleaseSelect2"/>
            <form:options items="${posts}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
        </form:select>
        <form:errors path="postId"/>
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 2px ;vertical-align:middle;border: 1px solid" id="addMoreElem">
        <img id="addMoreImage" src="/images/Plus.png" onclick='addMore("${postsString}")'  alt="<fmt:message key="button.addRow"></fmt:message>">
    </td>
  </table>
</form:form>
```

Now I want to append another rows to this table by clicking button in JavaScript. allPosts is an array which contains my combo box items in java script.
My jsp code for append to table is as follows:

```
function addMore(attr) {
    var data = "";
    data = "<tr>" +
           "<td style='padding: 2px;vertical-align:middle;border: 1px solid'>" +
           "<select name='postId'>" +
           "</select>" +
           "</td>"+
           "<td style='padding: 20px'  class='noBorder-fa' >" +
           "<img id='addMoreImage' src='/images/Plus.png' onclick='addMore("+attr+")'  alt='<fmt:message key="button.addRow"></fmt:message>' > " +
           "</td>" ;

   $("#customPostTable").append(data);
}
```

How can I append options to the select element with value of allPosts in JavaScript?

Comment: Note that, this is not `java`, it's `JavaScript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this works for you:

```js
function addMore(attr) {
    allPosts = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
    var data = "";
    all_Posts_Options = "";
    for(var i=0; i<allPosts.length; i++) {
      all_Posts_Options = all_Posts_Options + "<option>" + allPosts[i] + "</options>";
    }
    data = "<tr>" +
           "<td style='padding: 2px;vertical-align:middle;border: 1px solid'>" +
           "<select name='postId'>" +
           all_Posts_Options +
           "</select>" +
           "</td>"+
           "<td style='padding: 20px'  class='noBorder-fa' >" +
           "<img id='addMoreImage' src='/images/Plus.png' onclick='addMore()'  alt='<fmt:message key=\"button.addRow\"></fmt:message>' > " +
           "</td>" ;

   $("#customPostTable").append(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="customPostTable">
</table>
<button onclick="addMore(null)">Add more</button>
```

**Please note that inserting new elements via HTML is *not recommended*.

DOM manipulation tools shall be used instead**. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: Hi @sahar if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Another question: I want to insert new row when the option is selected in last row. How can i check this? In other words when the item is not selected, no permission to add new row.

Comment: @sahar. If you have a new question please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365580/add-more-row-button-work-when-combo-box-selected